# A bounded operator $T$ is compact if and only if $\sigma_{\mathrm{ess}}(T)=\{0\}$

Tags: operator-theory, sp.spectral-theory, hilbert-spaces

**Theorem:** Let $T$ be a bounded self-adjoint operator on a complex **infinite-dimensional** Hilbert space $H$. Then $T$ is compact if and only if $\sigma_{\mathrm{ess}}(T)=\{0\}$.

**Proof:** If $T$ is compact then by Hilbert-Schmidt I know that $\sigma_{\mathrm{ess}}(T)\subset\{0\}$. Furthermore if $E$ is the spectral resolution of $T$ then for all $\varepsilon>0$ we have
$$I-(E_\varepsilon-E_{-\varepsilon})\leq E(\{\lambda:|\lambda|>\varepsilon/2\})$$
but since $T$ is compact the operator $E(\{\lambda:|\lambda|>\varepsilon/2\})$ has finite range. So $\mathrm{rg}(I-(E_\varepsilon-E_{-\varepsilon}))=\ker(E_\varepsilon-E_{-\varepsilon})$ is finite dimensional but $$H=\ker(E_\varepsilon-E_{-\varepsilon})\oplus\mathrm{rg}(E_\varepsilon-E_{-\varepsilon}),$$ thus $\mathrm{rg}(E_\varepsilon-E_{-\varepsilon})=\infty$ and $0\in\sigma_{\mathrm{ess}}(T).$

I don't know how to prove the converse. I think I can use the following:
$$T\text{ is compact if and only if for all }\varepsilon>0,\text{ }\dim(\mathrm{rg}(E_\varepsilon-E_{-\varepsilon}))<\infty.$$

Can someone give me an idea? Thank you!

**Remark:** Here $E_\lambda:=E((-\infty,\lambda])$ for all $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: $T \equiv 0$ is compact and self-adjoint with $\sigma(T) = \sigma_p(T) = \{0\}$. Other counterexamples are operators with finite dimensional range.

Comment: I mean, $\lambda\in\sigma_{ess}(T)$ if and only if $\lambda$ is accumulation point of the spectrum of $T$ or $\dim\ker(T-\lambda)=\infty$. So $T\equiv 0$ implies that $\sigma(T)=\sigma_{ess}(T)=\{0\}$ because $H$ is infinite dimensional.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $\sigma_{\mathrm{ess}}(T)=\{0\}$. So, zero is the only one possible accumulation point.

Thus if $\sigma_d(T)$ is finite then $E(\{\lambda\in\mathbb{R}:|\lambda|>\varepsilon\})$ has finite range because it is the sum of projections on finite dimensional subspaces of $H$.

In the same way, if $\sigma_d(T)$ is infinite then $E(\{\lambda\in\mathbb{R}:|\lambda|>\varepsilon\})$ has finite range because $\{\lambda:|\lambda|>\varepsilon\}$ contains only finite eigenvalues ​​of finite multiplicity because $T$ is bounded.